# Extract a particular word from a cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have data in different cells from say  A1 to A2000

- **A1**
  XXXXXX  (Royal) 656565  7888888
- **A2**
  dfdfdfdf royal 6565659 0030303
- **A3**
  AAAAAAA RRRRRR XXXXXXXX FFFFFF
- **A4** 
  tyruijn tred jhdkdl (royal

Basically what i want is the word Royal should be extracted to coloumn b of the corresponding cell in which royal is there

Comment: Do you need to know how many times, or just whether it's in the cell or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In cell B1 and drag down

```
=iferror(if(search("Royal",A1)>0,"Royal",""),"")
```

or

```
=IFERROR(MID(A1,SEARCH("Royal",A1),5),"")
```

Comment: `=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("royal",A1)),"Royal","")` was what I was working on.

Answer (score 2):

I know this has already been answered.  Just want to show an alternate method:

```
=REPT("Royal",COUNTIF(A1,"*royal*"))
```